# What is the power source of Anakin Skywalker's podracer?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In "Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace" Anakin Skywalker participates in a race on Tatooine with his podracer to make some money to buy a hyper drive for Queen Amadala's ship and earn his freedom from slavery. Somehow he managed to win the Race.

My question is: What is the **power source** used in the podracer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rocket fuel

We know that the Pod uses fuel:

> Anakin’s sudden wrenching of his Pod’s steering took him spinning away into the midday, off course and out of control.
>   He pulled back on the steering, eased off on the thrusters, **cut the
>   fuel supply to the big engines**, and watched the ground rise up to meet
>   him in a rush of sand and reflected light.
>
> —*The Phantom Menace* (Terry Brooks)

And further:

> Anakin closed on them, drawing away from Mawhonic and Gasgano. People
>   said what they wanted about Watto—and there was plenty to say that
>   wasn’t good—but he had an eye for Podracers. The big engines jumped
>   obediently as Anakin fed fuel into the thrusters, and in seconds he
>   was drawing alongside Sebulba’s split-X.
>
> —*The Phantom Menace*

Specifically, it uses rocket fuel:

> Control cables ran from the Pod to the engines, and energy binders
>   locked the engines to each other. If any part of the three struck
>   something solid, the whole of the assembly would collapse in a
>   splintering of metal and a **fiery wash of rocket fuel**. If any part
>   broke free, it was all over.
>
> —*The Phantom Menace*

Answer (score -3):

In PhantomMenace, Qui-Gon gives Anakin a power source and ask him to use it for the upcoming pod race. The power source used specifically in Anakin's podracer, provided by Qui-Gon, that gave him the edge to win the race was most probably kyber krystals.

Comment: Do you have any evidence? The accepted answer does, and the evidence contradicts your point of view.

Comment: Qui-Gon does hand him something but everything else in the answer is speculation I believe

Comment: Qui-Gon gave him the power cell from his lightsaber (*"Qui-Gon Jinn appeared at his shoulder. “He handed the boy a small, bulky cylinder. “Use this power pack. I picked it up earlier in the day. Watto has less need for it than you.” One corner of his mouth twitched in a mix of embarrassment and amusement.
Anakin knew the value of a power pack. How the Jedi had managed to secure one from under Watto’s nose, he had no idea and no interest in finding out. “Yes, sir!” he beamed.")* - As far as I'm aware, those cells are not powered by Kyber crystals. Those are found elsewhere in the lightsaber.

Comment: Kyber crystals seem quite improbable.